# Applescript - What's the path of this "button" in System Preferences (Function Keys) / How to refer to Function Keys button in code

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, system-settings, path

I've been trying to write a script in AppleScript for making enabling and disabling Function Keys easier for me, but I cannot find the path for the Function Keys "button" in System Preferences.

[image: System Preferences - keyboard - shortcuts]

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click menu item "Keyboard" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    click button 1 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Settings"
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    click button ???
end tell
```

This opens the "Keyboard Shortcuts..." button in the window "Keyboard".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html) is really useful for determining the hierarchy of a UI element.

[image]

Therefore from this hierarchy we can find the element to click on.

`click UI element 1 of UI Element 1 of row 11 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Settings"`

The whole script can then look like this:

```
tell application "System Settings" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Settings"
    repeat
        try
            click menu item "Keyboard" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
    repeat
        try
            set keyboard to splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Keyboard"
            click button 1 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of keyboard
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
    repeat
        try
            click UI element 1 of UI element 1 of row 11 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of keyboard
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you're thinking of distributing this script be aware that as my Mac has a Touch Bar the second click needed to be `button 2` instead of `button 1`.

Comment: Thank you! My new question is: how do you run the script with a key combo shortcut? Because mine keeps failing using the Shortcut app while opening an Applescript.

Comment: @FanniGao If this answer answers the asked question, you should mark it as accepted (tick below votes on answer). The question you ask with your comment should be asked as another question.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found another solution

First, I've set a new App Shortcut with a key combination like <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for opening/pressing Function Keys in System Preferences, and integrated it in my script.

Here's a reference picture (sorry, it's in Hungarian):

[image: Screenshot of System Preferences]

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click menu item "Billentyűzet" of menu "Nézet" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    click button 1 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Billentyűzet" of application process "System Settings"
end tell

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {shift down, option down}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    click checkbox "Az F1, F2 stb. billentyűk használata szabványos funkciógombként" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Billentyűzet" of application process "System Settings" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

**It'd be like this in English:**

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click menu item "Keyboard" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    click button 1 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Settings"
end tell

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {shift down, option down}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    click checkbox "the exact name of the checkbox, the one with the F1, F2 etc. words in it" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Settings" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

Comment: In the English translation of the script, shouldn't the penultimate line `...group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Billentyűzet" of application...` say `... group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard" of application...`?